# How can i change screen resolution on mac remote control for a windows 2008 Server?

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, resolution, windows-server-2008, windows-server

I have a Server with Windows Server 2008 which i normally control over my Windows desktop PC that has a Screen resolution of 2,560 x 1,440 px.
The server tests multiple applications automatically for what simulates a mouse and control it. The Problem is, i'm in Hollidays now and have my Macbook Pro with me, wich has a Screen resolution of 2560 x 1600 but has less Inces. So i go to my Server to control everything is still running, and the server changes the simulated Sceen Resolution automatically to a smaller Inch. Now my program stops, cause it doesn't can hit the buttons anymore, they're now on another position. I'm not able to change the Programm cause i don't have the source code on my mac. So i wanted to ask, i there is an option to change the simulated size of the servers display?

Thx, Nico!

Comment: Did you try just full-screening the remote window? Green dot, top left.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't change anything. The only screen resolution i can choose is 1280x800px

Comment: Maybe try the beta - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/ - I've been using it so long I don't remember how poor the old version was [current beta has a bug that doesn't remember your screen positioning on the Mac, but is otherwise fine]

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin, it worked! I didn't knew the stable Version is this outdated ^^

Comment: I'll throw in something of an answer so we have completion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not normally the ideal solution to any problem, but for the past year or so Microsoft have had a running series of betas for the 'next generation' of RDC on Mac.

It isn't yet perfect but it can be, under many circumstances a better-behaved version than the current release.

See the announcement, with download links at MS TechNet ['Remote Desktop Client Preview for Mac supports multiple monitors and more'](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/) or the direct download from 'HockeyApp' which is a MS site at [Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta app for Mac](https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/)